# How to query a WMS "singletile:true, ratio:1" in Openlayers 3/4?

Tags: openlayers, wms

I have a WMS that renders a logo into a corner of all requested images. I want the logo to be visible in the corner of the OpenLayers map.
I am upgrading from Openlayes 2.13 to Openlayers 4.6.4

In [Openlayers 2 it worked by setting *ratio:1*](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Grid-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.ratio), singleTile: true

```
  var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(..., 
  {
    singleTile: true,
    ratio: 1,
  });
```

In Openlayers 4 I don't get the "ratio:1" option to work.

How can I setup Openlayers 4 to request WMS-images with the exact same size of the map-view?

**UPDATE**: The [current Single Image WMS example in OpenLayers 4](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html) documentation shows a *ratio: 1*, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Did you look https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html? There is a reference to ratio 1 in the sample. It could be what you are seeking?!

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had seen that, but I tested it thoroughly, and it has no effect. Seems to be a copy&paste bug in the OL 4 example.

Comment: The ratio option works as expected for me, i.e. the image from the WMS is requested with the exact same size as the map. Can you show an example where it does not?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out by debugging the Single Image WMS example

```
new ol.layer.Image({
      extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'blabla'
      })
    })
```

The **ratio option only works together with serverType**. Even if you don't have a WMS Geoserver. It also works with serverType: 'myserver'. It doesn't work when serverType is undefined.

Comment: I opened a ticket: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7755

Comment: Your snippet above does not work at all. However, it works when you remove the invalid `serverType`. I am unable to verify your observation that the `ratio` option only works together with `serverType`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did double check my post when I posted it, but I will double check it again.... next week ...